Postman Mock Server Simulate Delay Only on One Request
I'm using a Postman mock server to remove external dependencies while testing a process that calls an API. One of the scenarios we've found is that the API we're calling might not respond in a timely fashion. I know how to make the entire mock server simulate a network delay, but I'd like to have a specific endpoint in the collection just wait for X amount of time before responding.
I tried adding setTimeout(() => {}, 10000); to the pre-request script for that one mocked call, but it does not wait.
